# Как подключиться через прокси?

Tags: java, proxy

Стоит задача подключиться к сайту через proxy.
Прокси все в файле (HTTP/HTTPS).

```
String url = "https://iplogger.com/2qxn25", proxy = "139.59.72.192", port = "3128";
System.setProperty("http.proxySet", "true");
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost",proxy);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort",port);

URL site = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) site.openConnection();

connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setReadTimeout(15*1000);
connection.connect();
```

Как это сделать?
Ссылка на iplogger для того, чтобы проверить работает или нет.

Comment: Что вы уже предприняли для решения? Добавте ваш код.

Comment: Вот код что не так с ним?

Comment: "Прокси все в файле (HTTP/HTTPS)" - что вы имеете этим в виду?

Comment: То , что прокси будут находится в файле и оттуда будут тянутся

Comment: Прокси это комплекс программных, и возможно апаратных, средств. Как его можно тянуть из файла?

Comment: В файле они лежат так 127.0.0.1:8080 и я их тяну , я понял что я что-то не так сказал